# How to use WP-FirePHP extension?

Tags: plugins, debug

http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wp-firephp/

I'm simply supposed to call `fb('Error message','Lable')` but it doesn't work all the time. I can't figure out when and where the relevant files are being included and classes defined in order to make the call to the said method/function.

For example it doesn't work even when I call `fb()` from `wp-content\plugins\wp-firephp\FirePHPCore\fb.php` itself and open up `http://localhost/wordpress` (maybe because the file never gets included) but it works on `http://localhost/wordpress/wp-admin`. Does that mean `wp-firephp` plugin only works for `/wp-admin` and related pages? Because I wanted to use its functionality on non-admin related pages like `/footer.php` and such. Am I doing it wrong?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I gave up on using the plugin and use FirePHP straight as a `mu-plugin`:

[image: FirePHP mu-plugin]

And `firebug.php` file consists of:

```
<?php
/*
    Plugin Name: FirePHP
    Version: 0.1
*/

require_once( 'FirePHPCore/FirePHP.class.php' );
ob_start();
$firephp = FirePHP::getInstance( true );

function logit( $var, $title='From FirePHP:' )
{
    global $firephp;
    $firephp->log( $var, $title );
}
```

Then I call it from anywhere (theme, plugin, core) using the function:
`logit( $var_to_debug, 'The var contains:' );`

Comment: While using this method have you had any problems with FirePHP being instantiated so late in the game? I'd tried a similar approach and had some issues, that's why I instantiate in wp-config.

Comment: @Stephen, nope, don't remember having any issues. I mainly debug plugins, sometimes themes and rarely the core or in-depth features.

Answer (score 1):

I've had rotten luck and performance with the different FirePHP pluings except for the 'Yet Another Logger' one, but have to admit I didn't look at this one. Eventually I simply setup PEAR on my dev boxes and installed FirePHP.

```
/**
 * FirePHP simple examples
 */

// For FirePHP Object Oriented API
require_once('FirePHPCore/FirePHP.class.php');
$firephp = FirePHP::getInstance(true);
```

*or*

```
// Procedureal API
require_once('FirePHPCore/fb.php');
```

The above code is from the wp-config.php file of one of my development sites. It shows the two different methods of invoking FirePHP. *Remember use one or the other, not both.*

You call FirePHP by different methods depending upon how you invoke it.

For the Object Oriented API:

```
global $firephp;
$firephp->log( $var, "Label" );
```

For the Procedural API:

```
FB::log( $var, "Label" );
```

So after a slightly *off topic* answer:

Double check the documentation for the plugin and make sure you're not supposed to be using the procedural API style call. A procedural call will not work with the object oriented API and vice versa.

Another option would be to try the 'Yet Another Logger' plugin.