# pre_get_posts returning unformatted page

Tags: the-content, pre-get-posts

I ran a custom loop the other day to get some twitter information. Since I was running the code in a template and that template was being called from another loop, I was able to get the template data by doing this

```
 $content = $template->post_content;
 echo $content;
```

I figured this would be better than setting up another loop. When I did this, I found that the content was unformatted. So doing a little research, I found that if I pass it through the content filter

```
  $content = $template->post_content; 
  $content = apply_filters( 'the_content', $content); 
  echo $content;
```

tha solved my problem. So now I am using this function to get pages on my homepage and found that it does the same thing. It brings back the page unformatted

```
 function posts_and_pages_on_home( $query ) {
  if ( $query->is_main_query() ) {
    $query->set( 'post_type', array( 'post', 'page' ) );
    return $query;
  }
 }
 add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'posts_and_pages_on_home' );
```

So naturally, I figured that if I pass $query through the same content filter that it would fix my issue. Nope, I was wrong. Is there a way to get the function to filter the return $query through the_content filter?

Comment: Do you have a debugging tool like [FirePHP](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/71599/12615)? Today I saw [ChromePHP](https://plus.google.com/107110219316412982437/posts/gAcaXPU3Jqs) too. You'll be able to inspect your objects along the way of the code.

Comment: what's your home template code? The loop would be enaught...

Comment: I installed a plugin called "Debug This" is works pretty well to show me object data. I am still learning how to use it and how to debug code in this manner.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### The [`pre_get_posts`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/pre_get_posts) action hook only allows you to modify the [$query object](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query) .

Any formatting or output of data is done in the [template file](http://codex.wordpress.org/Stepping_Into_Templates) within [the loop](http://codex.wordpress.org/The_Loop).  When you are in the loop you have access to various [template tags](http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags) that output the post data formatted (filters applied).

```
if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();

    the_content(); //Same as echo apply_filters( 'the_content', $post->post_content );
```

Comment: my shortcodes don't get processed though and template files don't load. That is why I was wondering if something else needed to be done.