# How to customize a section of a widget only on certain pages or page

Tags: themes, widgets, child-theme, footer

I am using the twentynineteen default Wordpress theme but I would like to know how I can remove this line `<?php get_template_part( 'template-parts/footer/footer', 'widgets' ); ?>` only on certain pages in `footer.php`. Similar to this post: [How to add a specific widget to only 1 page?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/76959/how-to-add-a-specific-widget-to-only-1-page?newreg=cdab7c8f1f924f55a30447a1339c6c26). Basically, I would like to know how I can change a sections of a widget in a child theme on certain pages.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there's a simple way to force WordPress to exclude a template part, or load a different one. See [1](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/258844/how-to-add-custom-content-template-part-for-a-custom-post-type-on-main-query-usi) and [2](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/153004/is-it-possible-to-override-the-result-of-get-template-part/153012#153012) for some Stack Exchange discussion and workarounds. BUT in the special case of widgets, you can implement a filter (namely,`widget_display_callback`) in which you check where the widget is to be displayed, and what kind of page it might be displayed on, and tell WordPress not to display it (by returning `FALSE`). See more from Stack Exchange [3](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/57546/determining-a-widget-instance-and-sidebar-location) and the WordPress Code Reference [4](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/widget_display_callback/).

As far as workarounds go, probably the simplest is to use a CSS `display: none` to have the browser not display the widgets (or perhaps the entire widget area) on certain pages (if need be, there are simple ways to augment the CSS classes for the body tag to indicate what kind of page it is).

**Edit: addition**

Given that you'll want to make a child theme, and the Twentynineteen theme is well-organized, I thought of a couple of alternatives, which should be pretty simple.  
child theme with special template part  
in your child theme, make a `template-parts` directory,  make a `footer` directory inside it, then copy  `template-parts/footer/footer-widgets.php` from the Twentynineteen theme into the corresponding place in your child theme. Modify the copy to add your condition; something like this

```
if ( is_active_sidebar( 'sidebar-1' ) ) : ?>

    <aside class="widget-area" role="complementary" aria-label="<?php esc_attr_e( 'Footer', 'twentynineteen' ); ?>">
        <?php
            $cats = get_the_category();
            $cat_name = $cats[0]->name;
            print_r($cat_name);

            if ( is_active_sidebar( 'sidebar-1' ) and
                (strcasecmp('category with no footer widgets', $cat_name) == 0)) {
                ?>
                    <div class="widget-column footer-widget-1">
                        <?php dynamic_sidebar( 'sidebar-1' ); ?>
                    </div>
                <?php
            }
        ?>
    </aside><!-- .widget-area -->

<?php endif; ?>
```

- sidebars_widgets filter  
  Use the `sidebars_widgets` filter to remove the widget area entirely.
  something like
      add_filter( 'sidebars_widgets', 'remove_footer_widget_area' );

  ```
  function remove_footer_widget_area( $sidebars_widgets ) {
                  $cats = get_the_category();
                  $cat_name = $cats[0]->name;
                  if( (strcasecmp('category with no footer widgets', $cat_name) == 0) ) { 
                      unset($sidebars_widgets['sidebar-1']);
                  }
                  return $sidebars_widgets;
              }
  ```

  see [5](https://chrisblackwell.me/hide-widgets-specific-wordpress-pages/)

a few notes:  
— I'm assuming that the test as to whether to display the widgets depends on the category of the page, and the page is only in one category.   Modify as needed.  
— For historical reasons, `'sidebars'` here really means `'widget areas'`. WordPress is full of anachronisms like this.  
— Another anachronism is the function name `get_the_category()`, which gets an array of categories. So it really should be called `get_the_categories()`. 
— The second approach copies-and-modifies a template file from the parent theme. But the template is small and unlikely to change.